# Not holding anything sacred

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a term for a person who is able to take things lightly, joke about or satirize people, things and customs. Not in a cruel or mocking way but in a funny and insightful manner.

Comment: There is the word 'irreverant' which would answer the main question, but not necessarily the description. You can be irreverant in an insightful manner or in a mocking manner. Also I assume you don't want satirical since that's in the description.

Comment: Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered.

Comment: Yes...I think dry wit is it! Though dry wits are often accused of being irreverent, it's a fine line

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It could vary, depending on the specific context, but you could generally describe someone with those attributes as being witty, clever, astute, or even ingenious.
I would not use the word irreverent (note proper spelling) because that word has clear imprudent connotations of contempt and even disrespect.

Comment: Although a person who uses such satirical humour may be witty, clever, astute, and/or ingenious, none of those words imply satire. Witty is the only one of the four that implies any type of humour.

Comment: You're right..a dry wit is what i was looking for